# Convert JavaScript Date to .NET DateTime

Tags: javascript, .net, date, datetime

I getting a Date value from JavaScript to a controller in MVC and I would like to parse it to .NET format DateTime but its giving me an error such as:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The Format of the JavaScript date is:

```
"Wed May 23 2012 01:40:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)"
```

I've tried this but its not working:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(begin.Substring(1, 24), "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

anyone can give me a sample code please? thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of parsing a textual representation it would be more robust to construct a `DateTime` from a timestamp instead. To get a timestamp from a JS `Date`:

```
var msec = date.getTime();
```

And to convert `msec` (which represents a quantity of milliseconds) into a `DateTime`:

```
var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // epoch start
date = date.AddMilliseconds(msec); // you have to get this from JS of course
```

Comment: From .NET 4.6 use ```DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(msec).DateTime```

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy, simple, elegant and working solution, should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 25):

The following parses well with the default DateTime modelbinder in a .NET MVC Controller:

```
var myJsDate = new Date();
var myDotNetDate = myJsDate.toISOString();
```

Comment: perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did and why. I hope this Helps.

JS Date `var d = new Date()`

returns: Thu Nov 19 08:30:18 PST 2015

C# does not like this format so convert it to UTC:

```
var dc = d.toUTCString()
```

returns: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:30:18 UTC

UTC – The Worlds Time Standard is not a time zone so you need to change it to a time zone

```
var cr = dc.replace("UTC","GMT")
```

now it is ready to

Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:30:18 GMT

In one line

```
var ol = d.toUTCString().replace("UTC","GMT")`
```

Thu, 19 Nov 2015 16:30:18 GMT

for C#

```
DateTime DateCreated= DateTime.Parse(ol);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any conversion: the default DateTime modelbinder in a .NET MVC Controller works fine with a JavaScript Date object.

Using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

1) **.NET DateTime -> JavaScript Date**

```
var jsDate = moment(dotNetDateTime).toDate();
```

2) **JavaScript Date -> .NET DateTime**

```
var dotNetDateTime = jsDate;
```