# Why do I get a validation error when I use the jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have an `input` element rendered by the following Razor code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The `DateOfBirth` property is of type `DateTime?`. Then I have code to make elements with class `datepicker` act as date pickers:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: "button"
        }).next("button").button({
            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-calendar' },
            label: "Select a date",
            text: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I navigate to my view, I see the default date and the datepicker icon, and when I click the icon, I get the calendar drop-down. But, when I select a date, normally the first time, I get a validation errors, stating:

> The field DateOfBirth must be a date.

Then, when I select another date, the error vanished, only to return 'randomly' on subsequent date selections. I haven't been able to narrow down which dates cause errors and which don't; even when I keep both month and day under 13, to avoid potential issues with 'dd' vs. 'mm';. What could be causing these infuriating validation errors?

Comment: Not sure weather this is the cause or not but you are having different date format defined in razor(`dd/MM/yyyy`) and javascript (`dd/mm/yy`).

Comment: @JenishRabadiya One is the .NET date format, and the other is the JQuery UI format. These have always been different. Any date I select matches both formats, as far as I can see.

Comment: You could presumably get a `Date` out of a `DateTime`, something similar to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699851/) jQueryUI doesn't have its own class, it uses native js `Date`s. The `dateFormat` option is just for conveniencing working with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the date time format directly in the model. I changed your code and it worked fine for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {


    $('.dtPicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "button"
    }).next("button").button({
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-calendar' },
        label: "Select a date",
        text: false
    });


});
```

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("",""))
{

<fieldset>
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)
</div>
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.DoB)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.DoB,new {@class="dtPicker"})
</div>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</fieldset>
}



 public class DatePick
{
    [DisplayName("UserName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("DateOfBirth")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? DoB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome, and even after following your suggestion to format the field on the model, I still get the validation error. I also want to avoid formatting dates in the model, as this relies on every single date property having that attribute. I want to globally cover all date properties, eventually, with an editor template.

Comment: @ProfK Iam using chrome too.did you change this  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", in your script?

Comment: @ProfK this is working for me too. you should respect the guy who freely debugged your code and noted your typo and mark this as answer!

Comment: @SOOPAPP.COM I really appreciate not being told what to do, thank you. I have the deepest respect for the guy that posted the answer, but it didn't work for me. Accepting it would not only decrease my chances of getting other answers, but it would be a disservice to other SO users who have the same problem and this answer doesn't work for them either.