# .NET Core Web App AJAX call to Controller Action returning System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my .NET Core MVC web app I have several ajax calls to a controller action to update a SQL table via a stored procedure. One of these controller actions is returning an error and the responseText states "System.ArgumentNullException: Value Cannot Be Null. (Parameter 'value')" and I do not know why. No value is null. Below is the HTML code, JavaScript code, controller action, and the model for the data I am passing from the ajax call to the controller action.  When I remove the ID from the date input my code hits the controller action but the data being received is null. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

```
//HTML for milestone date and text field  
         <div class="tab-pane" id="milestones" role="tabpanel">
                        <br />
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <label>Milestone Date</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="@ViewBag.DateNoTime" id="milestoneDate">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <label>Milestone (MAX 30 characters) </label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" oninput="charLimit();" id="milestoneText" />
                                <p>
                                    <small class="text-danger" id="milestoneValidation" style="padding-top: 10px; display: none;">Please provide milestone text.</small>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary text-white" id="addMilestoneBtn" style="margin-top: 30px;">Add Milestone</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div id="milestoneTable"></div>
                    </div>
```

```
    //AJAX call to Milestones database table then rebuild form table
    $("#addMilestoneBtn").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loading-overlay').fadeIn();
        var date = new Date($("#milestoneDate").val());

        var milestoneDetails = {
            Id: 0,
            MilestoneName: $("#milestoneText").val(),
            ProjectId: Number($("#projectId").val()),
            Date: date

        };

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(milestoneDetails);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/TIB/Forms/MilestoneAddorUpdate',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnErrorCall
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var result = response;
            if (result == true) {             
                //$("#").html("Milestone addded successfully").css("color", "green");
                updateFormTables('milestoneTable');
                var today = moment().format('l');
                $("#milestoneDate").val(today);
                $("#milestoneText").val("");
                $('#loading-overlay').fadeOut();
            }        

        }

        function OnErrorCall(response) {
            //$("#").html("An Error has occurred. Please Try Again!").css("color", "red");
            alert("Error. Milestone not added. " + response.responseText);
            $('#loading-overlay').fadeOut();
        }

        return false;

    });
```

```
        //Controller Action to update Milestone in real-time
        [HttpPost("~/Forms/MilestoneAddorUpdate")]
        public bool MilestoneAddorUpdate([FromBody] Milestone milestone)
        {

            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("TIBDB")))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MilestoneAddorEdit", sqlConnection);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", milestone.Id);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProjectId", milestone.ProjectId);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", milestone.Date);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MilestoneName", milestone.MilestoneName);

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime dateOnly = date.Date;
            ViewBag.DateNoTime = date.ToString("d");

            return true;
        }
```

```
//Milestone Model
namespace TIB.Models
{
    public class Milestone
    {
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage ="Milestone cannot exceed 30 characters.")]  
        public string MilestoneName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Milestone Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d")]     
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        //Foreign Keys
        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }     
     
    }   

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing the date in the milestoneDetails object

Comment: @level_zebra That is a typo I corrected. I am passing the date value. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: try passing in the parameter name bit like this ` data: JSON.stringify({ milestone:{Id: 0,
            MilestoneName: $("#milestoneText").val(),
            ProjectId: Number($("#projectId").val()),
            Date: date}})`

Comment: @level_zebra That did not work. It produced the same error message as before.

Comment: @NerdyDroid, javascript dates are not the same as c# datetime, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30184408/1230756 it might help, also just before do your ajax post, console.log(jsonData) and make sure that is correct